# Connection Between two Variances of Connected Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ that can be thought of as a finite list of evenly spaced numbers (allowing repition). For simplicity lets say every number is of the form 0, .1, .2, ...., .9.

An example could be the data set / random variable $X = \{.1, .1, .2, .3, .9, .9, .9\}$. I am ignoring the formality that a random variable is defined as a function, whereas the set above can be used to determine the mapping. In this example $E[X] \approx .485$ and $Var(X) \approx .132$.

I could use this data to construct a new data set / random variable that represents the counts of each bucket from $X$, call this $X' = \{2,1,1,4\}$.

> Is there any known connections or knowledge relating two random
> variables of this form?  Is it relevant that values are evenly spaced?
> My ultimate goal is to make some simple yet quantified justifications
> that the original random variable $X$ either is or is not
> approximately uniformly distributed, and it seems to me a simple way
> would be to pass to the variance of $X'$.

I suppose there is a plethora of ways that $X$ may fail to be uniform, and which ways I care about could depend on what I am doing (is it atleast *randomly* not uniform, I think this is called heteroscedastic?).

I understand this is a pretty low quality (open ended) question, but hopefully before it gets closed someone will be able to interpret what I am trying to figure out and offer feedback so I can refine my question and post a better one.

The reason I am trying to pass to $X'$ is because I do not have access to which values the counts correspond to. E.g. I have the count values for $X'$ but it cannot be determined which bucket they correspond too, I do have 10 distinct count values. My thought is IF $X$ is uniform, then $Var(X') \approx 0$, so then apply the contrapositive. Further, is there a way I could scale $Var(X')$ to make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any kind of relation, and in fact there are examples of all four possibilities in which X is either high/low variance and same for X'.

X is high variance, X' is low variance:
X={1,9}, X'={1,1}

X is high variance, X' is high variance
X={1,.....,1,2,8,9,.....9}, X'={100,1,1,100}

X is low variance, X' is low variance:
X={1}, X'={1}

X is low variance, X' is high variance:
X={1,2,.....2}, X'={1,100}

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. Howabout if $E[X]$ is close to .9/2 and $Var(X')$ is low then I can say $X$ is somewhat approximating a uni dist